# CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_tax_class() on null

Tags: woocommerce

```
#0 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php(651): WC_Cart_Totals->get_items_from_cart()
#1 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php(143): WC_Cart_Totals->calculate_item_totals()
#2 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php(134): WC_Cart_Totals->calculate()
#3 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php(1401): WC_Cart_Totals->__construct(Object(WC_Cart))
#4 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-content/themes/affordablewebsites/inc/vendors/woocommerce/skins/fresh-el/functions.php(107): WC_Cart->calculate_totals()
#5 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): greenmart_quantity_button_action('')
#6 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#7 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#8 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php(94): do_action('wc_ajax_greenma...')
#9 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax('')
#10 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(false, Array)
#11 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#12 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(13): do_action('template_redire...')
#13 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/sites/2b/...')
#14 /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/sites/2b/...')
#15 {main}
  
thrown in /home/sites/2b/0/08245efc30/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php on line 225
```

This error has popped up now 8 - 10 times and no idea how to fix the issue. Its causing the website to go into "your site is experiencing technical difficulties" I taught it was a payment plugin issue so I switched it but now concerned it will keep happening.

Answer (score 0):

`get_tax_class()` method is inside `WC_Order_Item`. This is order item and you are calling `get_tax_class()` when this order item is `null`.

Why is this object `null` at that moment?
It's hard to tell without having access to the website and the code but I see there is an action `greenmart_quantity_button_action`, it looks like this is some ajax action probably triggered by some custom quantity button. Do you have something like that on the page? Some custom code or plugin?

Comment: Hi Ivo, thanks for the reply. There is the option to increase and decrease the quantity on the button itself when adding to cart you can click up or down on the quantity as seen here - https://el3.thembaydev.com/greenmart_fresh/

Comment: Ok, now it's important to see repeat this error somehow. Click every quantity button on the website (on the product page, inside the floating cart, on the cart page...) until you get the error. Maybe this happens only on some products. These random bugs are hard to catch. Also, you can check your custom code for that quantity hook. Sorry, it's hard to debug something random like this but I hope I at least gave you some general direction.